# Significance of multiple lines in JMeter results graph

Tags: graph, jmeter

I've run a test in JMeter. In the listener called "graph results", four blue lines appear for the average, four purple lines for the median and four green lines for the throughput.

My question is: why are there four lines instead of one single line for each concept? Which of the four is the good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior , "Graph Results" x-axis is able to accommodate maximum of 2000 points(means, if your cumulative sample count reaches to 2000 during the load test), after 2000 samples Jmeter will reset all counters (average , median, std ...) ,after resetting counters, the response times may increase, because of this increase you might notice multiple lines.

```
Senario: For [1- 2000] cumulative requests , the response time might be  Avg:228 ms, Medain 223, Standard Deviation 74.
For [2001-4000] cumulative requests , the response time might be  Avg:231 ms, Medain 229, Standard Deviation 78 or (response are the same).

To distinguish the graph for [1- 2000] will be first line for 
 [2001-4000] will be second and so on.
```